# static methods can only be declared in a static or top level type in Processing-Java

Tags: java, static, processing

so I was making a program in processing 3.5.4 -Java on Windows and a weird error came up. I looked online for ways to debug it but could not find a viable answer.

```
class ball{
  public PVector pos;
  public PVector vel;
  public int radius;
  public ball(int r){
    pos = new PVector(0,0);
    vel = new PVector(3/5,4/5);
    radius = r;
  }
  public void move(){
    pos.add(vel);

  }
  void render(){
        circle(pos.x,pos.y,radius);
  }

  public static PVector tanxd2(PVector inp){//finds value of tan(x/2)
  float hyp = sqrt(pow(inp.x,2)+pow(inp.y,2));
  float scl = 1/hyp;
  PVector ret = new PVector(scl*inp.y, scl*(hyp+inp.x));
  return ret;
}
};
```

and the line where the error arises is:-

> public static PVector tanxd2(PVector inp){//finds value of tan(x/2)

no other code is used and the error is:-

> The method tanxd2 cannot be declared static; static methods can only be declared in a static or top level type

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: What is not clear in the error message ? the answer is already given... move your method where you can declare a static method, or remove the static keyword...

Comment: Is `ball` an inner class? By the way, class names in java should start uppercase by convention.

Answer (score 3):

As the error message suggests, `static` methods may only be declared in *top level types* (classes that aren't inner classes). This is a restriction of Java.

But `Ball` is a top level type, right?

Well, actually it's not... And this arises from how Processing's preprocessor (the thing that converts `.pde` scripts into Java `.class` files) works.

During preprocessing, all classes become inner classes of a (currently invisible) parent class. Whereas in Java your `Ball` class would indeed be a top level type (because it has no enclosing parent class), this is no longer the case by the time your Processing script becomes runnable Java code (as exemplified below).

#### Example

Processing's preprocessor takes code that looks like this...

```
void setup() {...}

void draw() {...}

class Ball {...}
```

...and produces a resulting Java class that looks *something* like this:

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

final class JavaVersion extends PApplet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PApplet.main(JavaVersion.class);
    }

    @Override
    void setup() {...}
    
    @Override
    void draw() {...}
    
    class Ball {...} // ball is an inner class!

}
```

So back to the error message: Processing is simply enforcing a Java restriction – though of course it's not apparent that such code triggers such a restriction *until* we consider the preprocessor's behaviour.